# Return empty HTMLCollection in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, htmlcollection

I have a function that returns the child elements of a given (regular or shadowdom) element:

```
const getChildElements = (el: Element | null): HTMLCollection => {
  if (!el) {
    return [];
  }
  return el.shadowRoot ? el.shadowRoot.children : el.children;
};
```

I am getting a Typescript error on the first return statement that returns an empty array if the element is falsy.

> Type 'never[]' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLCollection': namedItem, item ts(2739)

Is there a way that I can return an empty HTMLCollection when the element is falsy?

Comment: Create an empty element and return its children? `return document.createElement('div').children;`

Comment: An `HTMLCollection` behaves like an array, but it is not an array.

Comment: of course the [spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection) notes: ***'HTMLCollection is a historical artifact we cannot rid the web of. While developers are of course welcome to keep using it, new API standard designers ought not to use it`***

Comment: @AlexWayne actually it doesn't behave much like an array except in very basic ways. It doesn't implement any of the standard array methods, and more importantly is a live collection responding in real time to changes to the DOM.

Comment: If you don't need a live collection, I'd say just return an array. You can wrap the `children` properties in `Array.from()`